# Max input file size of Design Automation for AutoCAD?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

I am working with Design Automation for AutoCAD.
I am investigating the Limits and Quotas. I would like to know the largest file size that can be uploaded in one job, and the maximum storage for a job.

I have searched in the 'Design Automation Rate Limit and Quotas' but still cannot find this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't document such limit. It depends on the free disk space of the processing server. Suffice to say it is 10s of GB. In the end of the day, it is unlikely that the file size will be the limiting factor in your ability to process the drawing. A multi-GB DWG file will likely take more time to process than the overall timeout we allow for a job (900s).